# Get Facebook Ad Insights for Ads that are no longer running

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am trying to get insights for ongoing and past Ads.

Using graph api

```
$fields2=array('fields' => 'cpc,clicks,impressions,actions,spend,reach,video_p100_watched_actions,video_p25_watched_actions,video_p50_watched_actions,video_p75_watched_actions,video_p95_watched_actions,video_avg_percent_watched_actions',
'time_increment' => "1",
'access_token'=>$token);
 $fields2=http_build_query($fields2);
 $curl2 = curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array($curl2, array(
                   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                   CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/$AD_ID/insights/?$fields2"
                   ));
```

After giving it an Ad ID I get all the metrics that I want, unless an AD is no longer running.

For all Ads that are no longer running, all I get is this

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to get insights for Ads that are no longer running? 
If so, which fields do I need to add?

Comment: Are the ads marked as "Complete" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to add an extra parameter:

```
'time_range' => "{'since':'2015-01-01', 'until':'2020-01-01'}"
```

...